# How to pass variables from AJAX form into controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have table on with reports(amount, date). I want user to choose date using datepickers and show reports, that are created between dates user's chose.

So I need to pass these variables from AJAX form.

I added AJAX form. Here is my **_form.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "financial_reports", :action => 'report', :remote => true) do%>
  <span id="pickers">From</span> 
  <%= datepicker_input "report","start_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy" %>
  <span id="pickers2">To</span>
  <%= datepicker_input "report", "end_date", :dateFormat => "dd/mm/yy"%>
<%=  submit_tag "Run Report", :class => "btn super", :id => "btn "%>
```

And I have partial, which is showing report. |

**_financial_report.erb.html**

```
 <table class="table" id="performance_report">
  <thead>
  <th>Date</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Currency</th>
  </thead>
 <% @financial_reports.each do |financial_report| %>
  <tr>
   <td> <%= financial_report.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")%></td> </td>
<td><%= financial_report.amount %></td>
<td><%= financial_report.currency %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
    <tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td><%= current_user.financial_reports.sum(:amount)%></td>
  </tr>
     </table>
```

and I am rendering this partials on my **index.erb.html**

```
            <div id="report_form"><%= render 'form' %></div>
             <%= render 'financial_report' %>
```

In my **report.js.erb** I want to return apporpiate reports:

```
         $('.report').apppend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@financial_report)) %>');
```

Here are my controllers(**I don't know where I should call "where" condition**

```
       def index
          @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports#.where(:created_at => the_start.to_date..the_end.to_date)
       ...
     end
```

or here

```
  def report
    @financial_reports = current_user.financial_reports#.where(:created_at => the_start.to_date..the_end.to_date)//here
     respond_to do |format|
    format.js
   end
  end
```

Here are my HTML of report form:

```
     <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/financial_reports/report?remote=true" method="post">
     <input id="report_start_date" name="report[start_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker">
      <input id="report_end_date" name="report[end_date]" size="30" type="text" class="hasDatepicker">
```

and in my routes:

```
        match 'financial_reports/report' => 'financial_reports#report'
```

I can get variables using AJAX:

```
  $.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST', 
  url: 'financial_reports/report', 
  data: {'start_date' : $("input[name='report[start_date]']").val(), 
    'end_date' : $("input[name='report[end_date]']").val() }, 
  success: function(data){
 //data is whatever you RETURN from your controller. 

    } 
 });
```

How should I solve this problem ? Maybe, I missunderstand AJAX stuff ?

P.S. When I'm calling report action it shows me blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are able to get a response from the ajax .
But are you returning anything from the action ? 
If the ajax request when fired explicitly works fine , that means your routes are fine . But the ajax request should trigger the javascript you have in `report.js.erb` . 
If that doesn't happen , I suspect parameters to be in the wrong format . I can see that in the ajax request you are passing :

```
  data: {'start_date' : $("input[name='report[start_date]']").val(), 
    'end_date' : $("input[name='report[end_date]']").val() }
```

This is fine if the action is expecting params[:start_date] and params[:end_date] . But the form does not send the params in that format .

My suggestion : 
With firebug or some other debugging tool , ensure it's a POST request , and the parameters should be in the expected format . Inspect the response of the request to see the return value . It should be a "success" response . Also check that the method "report" in the controller is a public method .

Answer (score 0):

In your report.js.erb you have a typo, **apppend** should be **append**

I am not sure if you have other issues, I didn't look further because that would already stop it working.